# Value error while executing logit regression code in python

Tags: python, logistic-regression

While running the following code for logistic regression:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logreg = LogisticRegression()

rfe = RFE(logreg, step= 20)
rfe = rfe.fit(data_final[X], data_final[y])
print(rfe.support_)
print(rfe.ranking_)
```

The error is shown as follows::

ValueError

```
    5 logreg = LogisticRegression()
      7 rfe = RFE(logreg, step= 20)
----> 8 rfe = rfe.fit(data_final[X], data_final[y])
      9 print(rfe.support_)
     10 print(rfe.ranking_)
```

Comment: What is the full error? Also please include minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it's likely that your facing this issue because of the format of your input data. You need to pass the features in "fit" as separate arguments. Here's how you can fix it

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Assuming X and y are lists or arrays containing your feature names and target variable name
X = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3']  # Replace with your actual feature names
y = 'target'  # Replace with your actual target variable name

logreg = LogisticRegression()

rfe = RFE(logreg, step=20)
rfe = rfe.fit(data_final[X], data_final[y])  # Separate X and y here
print(rfe.support_)
print(rfe.ranking_)
```

replace 'feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', and 'target' with your actual feature names and target variable name.